# Ansible: How to get a value of a variable from the inventory or group_vars file?

Tags: ansible

How do I get the value of a variable from the inventory if the variable could be either in the inventory file or `group_vars` directory?

For example, `region=place-a` could be in the inventory file or in a file in the `group_vars` somewhere. I would like a command to be able to retrieve that value using ansible or something retrieve that value. like:

```
$ ansible -i /somewhere/production/web --get-value region
place-a
```

That would help me with deployments and knowing which region is being deployed to.

.

A longer explanation to clarify, my inventory structure looks like this:

```
/somewhere/production/web
/somewhere/production/group_vars/web
```

The contents with the variables of the inventory file, `/somewhere/production/web` looks like this:

```
[web:children]
web1 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1
web2 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.2

[web:vars]
region=place-a
```

I could get the value from the inventory file by simply parsing the file. like so:

```
$ awk -F "=" '/^region/ {print $2}' /somewhere/production/web
place-a
```

But that variable could be in the `group_vars` file, too. For example:

```
$ cat /somewhere/production/group_vars/web
region: place-a
```

Or it could look like an array:

```
$ cat /somewhere/production/group_vars/web
region:
    - place-a
```

I don't want to look for and parse all the possible files.

Does Ansible have a way to get the values? Kind of like how it does with `--list-hosts`?

```
$ ansible web -i /somewhere/production/web --list-hosts
    web1
    web2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

**NO** there is no CLI option to get value of variables.

### Long Answer

First of all, you must look into how **variable precedence** works in Ansible.

The exact order is defined in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). Here is an summary excerpt:

> Basically, anything that goes into “role defaults” (the defaults
> folder inside the role) is the most malleable and easily overridden.
> Anything in the vars directory of the role overrides previous versions
> of that variable in namespace. The idea here to follow is that the
> more explicit you get in scope, the more precedence it takes with
> command line -e extra vars always winning. Host and/or inventory
> variables can win over role defaults, but not explicit includes like
> the vars directory or an include_vars task.

With that cleared out, the only way to see what value is a variable taking is to use the `debug` task as follows:

```
- name: debug a variable
  debug:
    var: region
```

This will print out the value of the variable `region`.

My suggestion would be to maintain a single value type, either a `string` or a `list` to prevent confusion across `tasks` in different `playbooks`.

You could use something like this:

```
- name: deploy to regions
  <task_type>:
    <task_options>: <task_option_value>
    // use the region variable as you wish
    region: {{ item }}
    ...
  with_items: "{{ regions.split(',') }}"
```

In this case you could have a variable `regions=us-west,us-east` comma-separated. The `with_items` statement would split it over the `,` and repeat the task for all the regions.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI version of this is important for people who are trying to connect ansible to other systems.  Building on the usage of the `copy` module elsewhere, if you have a POSIX `mktemp` and a copy of [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) locally, then here's a bash one-liner that does the trick from the CLI:

```
export TMP=`mktemp` && ansible localhost -c local -i inventory.yml -m copy -a "content={{hostvars['SOME_HOSTNAME']}} dest=${TMP}" >/dev/null && cat ${TMP}|jq -r .SOME_VAR_NAME && rm ${TMP}
```

Breaking it down

```
# create a tempfile
export TMP=`mktemp` 

# quietly use Ansible in local only mode, loading inventory.yml
# digging up the already-merged global/host/group vars 
# for SOME_HOSTNAME, copying them to our tempfile from before
ansible localhost --connection local \
  --inventory inventory.yml --module-name copy \
  --args "content={{hostvars['SOME_HOSTNAME']}} dest=${TMP}" \
  > /dev/null 

# CLI-embedded ansible is a bit cumbersome.  After all the data 
# is exported to JSON, we can use `jq` to get a lot more flexibility 
# out of queries/filters on this data.  Here we just want a single 
# value though, so we parse out SOME_VAR_NAME from all the host variables 
# we saved before
cat ${TMP}|jq -r .SOME_VAR_NAME
rm ${TMP}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more easy solution get a variable through cli from ansible could be this:

`export tmp_file=/tmp/ansible.$RANDOM
ansible -i <inventory> localhost -m copy -a "content={{ $VARIABLE_NAME }} dest=$tmp_file"
export VARIBALE_VALUE=$(cat $tmp_file)
rm -f $tmp_file`

Looks quite ugly but is really helpful.